# While applying UK visa should I declare that I am visiting Schengen countries?

Tags: visas

I am from India. I want to visit London, Paris and Amsterdam.
I fly and reach London on 25th April and Fly Back to India from London on 12th May Night.
My stay at UK will be at my cousin's place, who is a British Citizen.

In between I intend to keep 7 days for my visit to France (Paris 4 days)and the Netherlands, (Amsterdam 3 days).
Want to apply for Schengen Visa once granted a UK visa. Therefore my actual stay in UK will be for *10 days*.
Now, In Que **"How long do you intend to stay in the UK?"** do I say *17 Days, and not reveal that I would visit France and Amsterdam in between*? or *mention 10 Days and say that I want to Visit France and the Netherlands for 7 days in the Additional Information*?

Comment: Do tell them as much as possible, it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do as a tourist, there is no downside. If you are unsure about some parts of the form, there is usually a box at the end to add further info or clarify things. You can even attach a letter with more details (although that's probably overkill in this case).

Comment: It's also worth bearing in mind that you'll be entering the UK twice, once when you land from India and once when you return from the Schengen zone.

Answer (score 7):

You should definitely mention your plans to visit France and the Netherlands.  Otherwise, you might be issued a single-entry visa, which would prevent you from visiting those countries and subsequently returning to the UK.

In addition, you should in principle be forthcoming about details of your travel plans.  Otherwise you might be suspected of being evasive, which will "damage your credibility" and almost certainly result in the application being refused.

As to whether your trip counts as 10 days in the UK or 17, I am pretty sure it's the former, but there won't likely be a difference in your chances of success.  They'll want to see that you can afford the entire 17-day trip, for example.  As long as you provide your detailed itinerary, there shouldn't be any problem if you answer 17 where they'd rather see 10, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I luckily did the same and declared that... Please also tell if Travel Insurance is required to be presented to VFS at the time of appointment along with other documents???

Comment: @PankajKumar I don't know anything about travel insurance requirements; sorry.  In any event, that's a new question, and should be posted as a new question.